# Google Analytics using React Web / Cordova

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

I have made an app using React (Web) and bundled it using Cordova.

I am using a plugin called 'react-ga' for tracking Google Analytics.

I initialise react-ga when the app is run using:

```
ReactGA.initialize('my-ga-uid', { debug: true, cookieDomain: 'auto' })
```

And create an event using something like:

```
ReactGA.event({
  category: 'Test',
  action: 'Test button pressed event.'
})
```

or,

```
ReactGA.set({ location.pathname })
ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname)
```

The analytics work fine in the browser and on dev builds, however when I bundle a build for iOS or Android, the analytics don't seem to be tracked?

Is there something wrong with my code? Do I need to initialise something else? Do I need a cordova plugin instead (although I want analytics to still work in a web browser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ReactGA.set({ checkProtocolTask: null }) // Disable file protocol checking.
```

Comment: This got me past the "Unallowed document protocol. Aborting hit" error but now I'm getting "Storage not available. Aborting hit".

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a GA property for your mobile app that is a separate property from your website.  When you set up a new property, you have the option to choose between a website and a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `ReactGA` in an Android webview:

I needed to do the following:

```
  ReactGA.set({ checkProtocolTask: null, checkStorageTask: null })
```

to get passed the following errors:

```
"Unallowed document protocol. Aborting hit" 
"Storage not available. Aborting hit."
```